# Xamarin Workbook and Visual Studio gives different result

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, cocoa

I am facing an issue with the API returning different results when run from the Visual Studio and Xamarin Workbook also when the app is built from Bamboo.

The code that gives strange result is this:

```
 var platformLocations = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("/Users/anoopvaidya")
            .Select(s => new DirectoryInfo(s))
            .Where(s => s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
            .Where(s => !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
            .Where(s => !s.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
            .Where(s => !s.Name.StartsWith(".") &&
                        !s.Name.StartsWith("Vxxxxxxxx"));
```

As you see the screenshot of the output from Visual Studio and Xamarin Workbook.
[image]

[image]

My expected result is NOT to have the Library folder in the `platformLocations` array.

Can someone guide me what is wrong here and/or I need to use a different API to achieve this?

Comment: have you narrowed down which test condition is different between the two environments?

Comment: @Jason: both are the same, isn't it?

Comment: obviously not, or you wouldn't get different results.  I'm going to guess that for some reason one considers Library a system folder and one does not.  But I would validate that assumption first.

Comment: The project you have in Visual Studio, what type of project is it. Which Target Platform is it using?

Comment: @Cheesebaron: macOS 10.14+

Comment: No. In the csproj file. What is the exact target platform in there?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya First, the `Library` exists actually in Mac.Second, the difference between them may be permission result of VS not shows and WorkBook shows.